# Facebook application - extended permissions

Tags: facebook

I been reading about Facebook applications for a couple of days now. I created an application and got an ID and SECRET.

The documentation recommends to use "Graph" for gaining extended permissions.

My question is, is it optional to have a popup, just like the rest of Facebook's popups? (a layer on-top the current screen, without an actual 'Window')?

My application is inside facebook, accessible using http://apps.facebook.com//
My goal is to ask friends of mine to grant this application: publish_stream and offline_access. Then I'm supposed to store their UIDs while granting, and I'm entitled to automatically share items on their "stream"? even a week after they've logged off?

Thanks.
Doori Bar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the idea. You request the permissions when they log in to the application and then iterate over the response to see if they actually granted them. If they did you can then use the information to publish to the stream.

Comment: Is it optional to have it as a popup which is a JS-layer on-top the current screen? (not an actual 'window'). Do I need to store their UIDs locally? will I be able to publish to their stream even a week after they logged off?

Comment: @Doori: Yes, I believe. Yes, I believe you are charged with storing them. And yes, you should be able to publish.

Comment: The thing is, I haven't found even one sample of such popup using Graph, and I haven't found anything on the documentation about a local db for storing any info. Regards UIDs, I found confusing statements about when I should use them, which didn't make sense in regard to offline_access

Comment: @Doori: The documentation for Graph is terrible. I suggest you ask on the Facebook Developer forums.